# When slope is undefined, output is undefined instead of error message

Tags: warning-messages

This simple program returns the slope and the equation of a line when two points are selected in Manipulate.  If the line is vertical, I want to intervene before Mathematica's error message. I want to print the error message "Undefined" for slope. I have searched StackExchange and have not found an answer.

This would occur when the run is 0.  I think I need an if/then statement with if run=0, then slope is undefined. But how do I incorporate that into the PlotLabel?

```
Manipulate[
 rise[p_, q_] := p[[2]] - q[[2]];
 run[p_, q_] := p[[1]] - q[[1]];
 slope[p_, q_] := rise[p, q]/run[p, q];
 yintercept[p_, q_] := p[[2]] - slope[p, q]*p[[1]];
 Graphics[
    Line[{p, q}],
    PlotRange -> 10.10,
    Frame -> True,
    Axes -> True,
    AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
    AxesStyle -> Thick,

    FrameTicks -> {{-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4,
      5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1,
      2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}},
    GridLines -> {{-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
     6, 7, 8, 9}, {-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
     6, 7, 8, 9}},
    ImageSize ->  500,
    PlotLabel -> 
   Row[{"(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)]\) , \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\
\), \(1\)]\)) = ", p, 
     "\t (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\) , \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\
\), \(2\)]\)) = ", q, 
     "\t slope = (", rise[p, q] "/", run[p, q], ") = " , slope[p, q], 
     "\n The equation of this line is y = ", slope[p, q] , "x + ", 
     yintercept[p, q] }]
    ],
 {{p, {-5, -1}}, Locator}, 
 {{q, {2, 7}}, Locator}
    ]
```

Comment: Why not simply use `slope[p_, q_] := Module[{r = run[p, q]}, If[r == 0, Infinity, rise[p, q]/r]];`  ? You can change the definition as needed to handle the special case. I do not know what logic you are using. You change the above as needed to check for this special case and return different result if needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[

 rise[p_, q_] := p[[2]] - q[[2]];
 run[p_, q_] := p[[1]] - q[[1]];
 slope[p_, q_] := 
  With[{r = run[p, q]}, If[r == 0, "na", rise[p, q]/run[p, q]]];
 yintercept[p_, q_] := p[[2]] - slope[p, q]*p[[1]];

 Graphics[
  Line[{p, q}],
  PlotRange -> 10.10,
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {x, y},
  AxesStyle -> Thick,
  FrameTicks -> {Range[-10, 10], Range[-10, 10]},
  GridLines -> {Range[-9, 9], Range[-9, 9]},
  ImageSize -> 500,
  PlotLabel ->
   Row[{"x1, y1 = ", p,
     "\t (x2 , y2) = ", q,
     "\t slope = (", rise[p, q] "/", run[p, q], ") = ", slope[p, q],
     "\n The equation of this line is y = ", slope[p, q], "x + ", 
     yintercept[p, q]}]],
 {{p, {-5, -1}}, Locator}, {{q, {2, 7}}, Locator},
 TrackedSymbols :> {p, q}]
```

[image]

I prevented zero-division within `slope` (see image) and added `TrackedSymbols`to prevent screen flickering. I replaced the subscripts for better readability here.

Comment: When I copy and paste your code the result is a plot that shows it is evaluating constantly (the cell bar is colored). I moved the function definitions (e.g., `rise`, `run`, etc) outside of `Manipulate` and the problem went away.